# Company-specific tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Would it be appropriate to create a tag for questions about a specific hosting or domain registration company?

In the last 6 months there have been, on average, one relevant question per month: company-specific tags would help people find similar issues and assist the members of companies' staff who monitor online forums.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have lots of tags with company and product names so I don't think this will be a problem at all.

Examples: [google](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) [microsoft](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) [google-analytics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics)

Comment: Also godaddy which is a similar company to 123-reg.

Answer (score 0):

### Pro Webmasters has a very unique opportunity.

It's hard to find a reliable resource on domain registration or hosting.  The answers will have to watched closely due to the potential for spam.

Comment: This might be too *subjective*

Comment: Ya your right.  I edited it.